# Boost timer doesn't compile

Tags: c++, boost, timer

I'm trying to compile the boost timer and it's throwing errors I don't understand. It makes me think the timer library is broken atm:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
//  auto_cpu_timer t;
    std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(2.0) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Without the #include for timer.hpp it compiles. With it, it throws the following errors:

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -Lsrc -o "timetest"  ./src/main.o   
./src/main.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [timetest] Error 1
```

Does this mean the timer library is busted atm? I'm using Boost 1.49.0.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it really too much to ask for a little google-fu? We have thousands of `undefined reference` questions here. They are all the same.

Comment: Did you copy-paste that program directly, or did you type it in? You seem to be missing, at least, `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: @pmr I did a few minutes of google and stackoverflow, but my queries were too specific I guess. My mistake!

Comment: @Robᵩ I copy/pasted. Good point about iostream, but it actually compiles and executes fine on my system which I'm a bit confused about now.

Comment: @JacobBlock Chances are `lexical_cast` is pulling in `iostream`. I don't know how you managed to be more specific than `boost undefined reference boost system gcc` You can leave out words at choice and still get perfect results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you use gcc, try adding -lboost_system to your compiler command line in order to link against that library.

Comment: I guess I'm still getting mixed up on includes and library linking. Works now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Those errors are not related to the Boost Timer library and no, the library is not broken. As this [introductory material](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html) specifies,

> Boost.Timer is implemented as a separately compiled library, so you must install binaries in a location that can be found by your linker.

... and add the according libraries as command line arguments (using `-lLIBNAME`) when invoking the compiler or add them to your project configuration if using an IDE, CMake or Makefiles. Make sure you first understand the details discussed in the [Boost Getting Started guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/more/getting_started/index.html) before making cheap remarks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to include The base boost system headers too. Check one of The examples for The default headers you need.

Comment: this is not about headers, but linking libraries

Comment: woops, didnt see it was a linker error. Last time i try to use the SO mobile app to answer a question =\

Answer (score 0):

You forget to link boost_system.
Like this:

```
g++ -Lsrc -o "timetest"  ./src/main.o -lboost_system
```

will fine